# Designing a layout with a picture and a long paragraph

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to design the following layout for a flutter web app

[image]

There is an image on the left, and on it's right, the paragraph starts, but once the right side of the image has been filled with text, I want the paragraph to continue from below the image as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try RichText Widget something like below : (Haven't tested)

```
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              WidgetSpan(
                  child: SizedBox(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 150,
                      child: Image.network(
                          "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_1280.png"))),
              TextSpan(
                  text: text,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

OR

You can have both image and text in HTML format then render HTML in flutter using [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) package.

```
<p><img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140" style="float:left;">
Your long text here
</p>
```

I hope this helps you !

Comment: I tried using the RichText widget, but text overflows from the right side, it doesn't go into the 2nd line. I also used softWrap = false, so text starts from the right (if not used it starts below the image), and even if i added a very long text, it wouldn't continue from below the image, it stays there as if it's a row